# "Exactly" as a modifier

Tags: adverbs

I read one question here but the word in this post is *mostly* and I thought it might be irrelevant to my case.

> The box contained **exactly** three pens.

One function of adverbs is that they modify the verb. However, in the sentence above, I think *exactly* modifies *three* - an adjective.

Am I wrong?

Comment: In general, an adverb can modify a verb, an adjective, or another adverb.  But, of course, as is always the case with English, "in general" has a lot of specific exceptions and special provisions.

Comment: @HotLicks I want to find which function of _exactly_ in this sentence rather than discuss about the function of adverbs in general. Thank you.

Comment: 'three' means 'at least three', so 'exactly three' increases the precision

Comment: Yes, it modifies _three_, but _three_ isn't an adjective.

Comment: "Exactly three" is a determinative phrase (DP) headed by the determinative "three" which is modified by the adverb "exactly".

Comment: Yes. This kind of determinative phrase is also called a quantifier or determiner. And adverbs can modify them, just like they can modify adjectives and other adverbs.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It is the first time I heard about DP. I always think of numbers as adjective instead of determiner.

Answer (score 0):

The construction above is pretty uncommon - specifically the use of **exactly three** - but it's entirely grammatical, and the adverb is indeed modifying the adjective. The structure makes more sense with a larger number:

> Each tin contained **exactly** one hundred and fifty-seven sweets

The adverb is clarifying that the number that follows it is not an approximation or an average, but a firm and concrete amount. That's why it's not normally used with numbers as low as three - three of anything is easily identifiable by sight, and there's no expectation that the number might be anything but exact.

However, it's often used to *emphasise* how low a number is, by using a structure normally associated with much larger numbers. At first glance, that is what I would assume was being done in your example.